# Can we use QueueBrowser just to browse messages in current queue from sender side?

Tags: java, queue, jms, messaging

I'm new to JMS Queue. Please advice me on the following:

Do we need to use the QueueBrowser.getEnumeration() only at the client end, just before consuming the next message? Or can we use it from the sender side to browse the messages in the queue which we can retrieve from the context using the queuename?

Is there any restrictions to be followed to browse messages of a queue? Because I never get elements in QueueBrowser.getEnumeration(); always it was an empty one!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A `QueueBrowser` as the name `Browser` suggests,is required if you want to take a look at a message in a queue without removing it from the queue. On the other hand a `QueueReceiver` is used to receive message and remove it from the queue.

Unless there is a specific requirement, there is no need to use QueueBrowser to inspect a message and then use QueueReceiver to consume messages. You can consume messages in the order they are produced or use selector to consume messages that match a certain criteria.

There is no restriction on using QueueBrowser anywhere, sender or receiver, based on your application design requirements.

Comment: Thank you, Shashi! Now I have some knowledge about Queue & QueueBrowser. However as I mentioned above, I'm always getting empty list from getEnumeration() method for the queue created by myself. But I'm getting the content as it is from default queues like DLQ and Expiry Queue. 

That's why I asked about restrictions/configurations involved in creating/browsing a queue.

Comment: I am assuming you have messages in the queue you created?

Comment: Yes, the queue has messages for sure. I confirmed it with admin-console of jboss. Though the console shows more than 20 messages exist in queue, I can't browse them using QueueBrowser. Check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28408438/unable-to-browse-queues-using-jms-queuebrowser